# Problems with relative layout: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, android-relativelayout

I'm going crazy with this problem...
I would like to do something like this:
[image]

This is my SIMPLY code into the xml layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <WebView
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/webView1"
        p1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        p1:layout_above="@id/textView1" />
    <TextView
        p1:text="Medium Text"
        p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/textView1"
        p1:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but the error that I receive is this:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/textView1').

That is so strange for me.... because I have specified textView1!!!!

Some idea?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TextView` with the id `textView1` is parsed after the `WebView` that is referencing it. Using the `@id/*` syntax specifies that the parser is resolving an existing id. In this case it will fail as your `TextView` hasn't been parsed yet.

Use `layout_above=@+id/textView1` instead to predeclare the id for your TextView.

Comment: Yes I've noted this. The layout editor fails when you connect two object.... It misses The '+' symbol between @ and id!!! Thanks Matt.

Comment: If it fixed your problem, it's generally good to have it marked as accepted so future readers know its a solution. :)

Comment: This did not work for me, I had to re-order the elements of my .axml file to get it to build